# Cisco AnyConnect "web security unavailable" - Mac OS High Sierra & Mojave

Tags: macos-high-sierra, cisco, macos-mojave, websecurity

After upgrading my Mac OS to High Sierra or Mojave I've got this error message "web security unavailable" with a a big red X in the menu icon

Answer (score -1):

The problem could be that no app / module can be downloaded from authorized developer. A possible workaround could be to open "System Preferences" => "Security & Privacy" and the "General Tab" to allow the installation of software coming from authorized developer.